# Please explain this c++ for loop, iside a for loop. Update 2

Tags: c++, codeblocks

It might be the lack of sleep,

I do not get in what order the rectangle is constructed. length first then height?

And why are the `cin>>` values used as the amount of `*` to output if the only `cout<<` indicated is `"*"`?

I know it's noob stuff for a lot of you, so please explain it like I was a 5 yo :D

The code was edited, again, in english this time. Thank you for pointing that error, need more coffee :/

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void drawRectangle ( int l, int h )
{
for ( int line (0); line < h; line++ )
{
    for ( int column (0); column < l; column++ )
    {
        cout << "*";
    }

     cout<<endl;
}
}
int main()
{
int length, height;
cout << "Length for rectangle : ";
cin >> length;

cout << "Height for rectangle : ";
cin >> height;

drawRectangle (length, height);

return 0;
}
```

UPDATE 1:

Thank you to all who answered, even when the code was messed up. I just want to make sure I understand:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void drawRectangle ( int l, int h )

{
for ( int line (0); line < h; line++ ) //this is the outer loop
{
for ( int column (0); column < l; column++ ) //this is the inner loop
{
    cout << "*";
}
cout<<endl; //the length is written then jumps here to break.

/*So, the outer loop writes the length,from left to right, jumps to the cout<<endl; for a line break, then the inner loop writes the height under each "*" that forms the length?/*
```

UPDATE 2: Got my answer right here 
   http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=326

I guess this mystery is    solved! Thank you to everyone that answered my question :) I appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think this is proper syntax: `for (int line(0); line < h; line++) }`. Is a brace in the wrong position?

Comment: *so please explain it like I was a 5 yo*: When a mommy `for` loop and a daddy `for` loop love each other very much, they nest inside each other and produce a compilation error: [`Line 13: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token`](http://codepad.org/AvBcGf1o) When you're older, son, you'll learn how to post code that compiles.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: That was an awesome explanation. Perhaps he took an arrow to the knee.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one's complained about how inefficient the chosen algorithm is. It would be much wiser to construct an `std::string` of `l` asterisks and a newline, then print it `h` times. Bonus points for constructing the whole output string first, but only if `l` and `h` are guaranteed to be sufficiently small. More efficiency points if you skip `std::string` and go straight for a `char` array.

Comment: Code's been edited to be in a different language! First time I've seen that before. And I'm not talking C++ to VB.

Comment: Why not go to bed, and post again when you're awake? If *you* are in no state to think about your code, why should any of us be?

Comment: Hi KSB :) I really do appreciate the feedback, great place to learn when there is no one around that can help a noob.I cant afford to sleep, but I will close my eyes for a bit then keep going, cant stop!

Comment: Voting to close because it's still difficult or impossible to figure out what the question is asking, and because it's apparently already been solved by the asker. No need for an influx of confused answers.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't actually construct anything, since **it doesn't compile**. :/

Changing `drawRectangle` to the following (by putting the braces where they should be) will make it compile and run (*however what you consider to be the length and height are back to front*):

```
void drawRectangle( int l, int h )
{
     for ( int column (0); column < l; column++ )
     {
         for ( int line (0); line < h; line++ )
         {
            cout << "*";
         }

         cout<<endl;
     }
}
```

Assume `l` is 5 and `h` is 4 (`drawRectangle(5, 4)`). The outside `for` loop will iterate 5 times, creating 5 rows. Now for each of those rows, the inside `for` loop iterates 4 times, and prints a `'*'` at each iteration (therefore `****` is printed for each row). Once the inner `for` loop terminates, a new line is printed, and the outside one continues until it has iterated 5 times.

And you get:

```
****
****
****
****
****
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{` syntax is a bit wrong in the loops.

To answer your question the rectangle is draw with a number of * starting on column 1 drawing the whole row like this:

```
*    *    *
*    *    *
* => * => *
*    *    *
*    *    *
```

this is a length = 3 and height = 5 rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Very messy code you have there.

```
void drawRectangle(int l, int h)
{
     for ( int column = 0; column < l; column++ )
     {
         for ( int line = 0; line < h; line++ )
         {
             cout << "*";
         }
         cout<<endl;
     }
}
```

Since the console output goes from left to right, you have to output the lenth first. You do this by putting `cout << "*"` into the inner loop. The outer loop puts a line break after your length was written. The ouput would look like:

```
****************
****************
****************
****************
```

with length=16 and height=4